# Why is this script repeating itself?

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I'm trying to teach myself python, I recently learned how to use raw input in an if statement (`yes` or `no`). However, when I answer `yes`, the program asks me the same if question.
Can anyone help? I'm not really good at programming but love doing it.

```
import time
name = raw_input("what is your name? ")
print "Hello " + name
#yes no statement with raw input
while True:
        yesno = raw_input("would you like to play hangman?")
        if yesno.lower().startswith("n"):
                print("ok bye")
                exit()
        elif yesno.lower().startswith("y"):
                print("cool, let me prep for e second")
                time.sleep(5)
# this is where it goes wrong
# below is what is supposed to follow
word = "kaasblok"
guesses = ''
turns = 6
while turns > 0:
```

Comment: because it's inside a `while True:` (and therefore neverending) loop

Comment: You probably want a `break` immediately following `time.sleep`.

Comment: You are using python 2.x but its at end-of-life. Learn python 3 instead. It has many new features/

Comment: If you are just teaching yourself Python, ditch Python 2 and install Python 3.

Comment: @RobinZigmond i feel incredibly stupid now.... thanks!

Comment: @tdelaney will keep that in mind!

Comment: The break should be directly below `time.sleep(5)` (or replace it if you don't want the sleep any more)

Comment: @tdelaney now it just remains on cool let me prep for a second. (btw, sorry if i'm bothering you or anyone with these questions)

Answer (score 1):

If you use a while true loop, your program will keep on running.

In Python, the tabs or whitespace tell the interpreter when a loop ends.

So what happens in your code is this:

While True is running,
   It asks if you want to play
   If you write no it works as intended
   If you write yes, it sees that the loop is over so it restarts.

Also your code has several errors, like syntax from both Python 3 and Python 2 and a while loop that doesn't terminate.

I wrote some updates to make the code sort of work but it is not "good" code because I tried to keep it as similar as possible. Also I chose a syntax (python 3) so make sure to change that if you're using Python 2.

I recommend you modularize your code and look at other people's code, it'll make your code better. Avoid using a while True loop, at least at the beginning. The code I wrote sort of tries to address it, but it probably doesn't do such a great job.

Maybe try editing the code a bit and updating with an answer later? I think you meant to write input, not raw_input but it could be that's the way you do it in Python 2. You should really learn Python 3 if you're trying to pick up Python btw as Python 2 is at its end of life cycle.

Place your game in the loop and it'll run. Try something like this:

```
import time
name = input("what is your name? ")
word = "kaasblok"
turns = 6

print("Hello " + name)
#yes no statement with raw input
trueorfalse = True
while trueorfalse:
        yesno = input("would you like to play hangman?")
        if yesno.lower().startswith("n"):
                print("ok bye")
                #trueorfalse = False
                break
        elif yesno.lower().startswith("y"):
                print("cool, let me prep...")
                time.sleep(1)
# Place your code in the elif block
                while turns > 0:
                    guess = input("what is the word")
                    if guess == word:
                        print('win')
                        #trueorfalse = False
                        break

                    else:
                        turns -=1
                        print("you have these many turns left", turns)
                print("you lost")
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

All that's missing is a way to break out of the while loop. So, use the `break` command.

```
import time
name = raw_input("what is your name? ")
print "Hello " + name
#yes no statement with raw input
while True:
        yesno = raw_input("would you like to play hangman?")
        if yesno.lower().startswith("n"):
                print("ok bye")
                exit()
        elif yesno.lower().startswith("y"):
                print("cool, let me prep for e second")
                time.sleep(5)
                break # <-- break out of of the current loop

print "made it!"
```